# why compiler is not eliding away copy construction in this case

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

```
class test
{

public:

    int data;
    test(int var = 0):data(var){cout<<"constructor"<<endl;}
    ~test(){ cout<<"destructor"<<endl; }

    test(const test& var)
    {
        cout<<"copy constructor"<<endl;
        this->data = var.data;

    }
    test& operator=( const test& var)
    {
        cout<<"assignment op"<<endl;
        this->data = var.data;
        return *this;
    }

};


test passByref_returnByVal(test& obj)    
{    
    return obj;    
}


int main()
{

    test o1(5);
    test o2 = passByref_returnByVal(o1);
    cout<<"=========================="<<endl;
    test o3;
    o3 = passByref_returnByVal(o1);   
}
```

Output:

```
constructor

copy constructor

constructor

copy constructor

assignment op

destructor
```

In the given example , object `o2` is directly copy constructed without using any temporaries.

But in the second case where i want `o3` to be assigned the return value of the function, first a temporary is created using the copy constructor and then assignment operator is called for value assignment.

My question is what was the need for this temporary as my assignment operator takes reference. I found related questions but they didnt answer this.

Comment: I don't believe this output came from this code: in particular, I didn't find the "==========" marker in your output.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I've just queued an edit to do that. Have patience while it gets through the review system! :-)

Comment: thanks for the edit.. my edit didnt go through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
test o3;
```

will cause a call to the constructor to create the object.  C++ isn't Java where an object type declaration only declares a references but doesn't instantiate an object.

```
test passByref_returnByVal(test& obj) {....}
```

causes the copy constructor call because when inside of it you do `return obj;` the compiler needs to create a temporary object because the return type of that function is `test` (as opposed to `test&` or `test*`).

Finally, because `o3` already exists courtesy of the

```
test o3;
```

declaration, the assignment operator is called to assign the return value of `passByref_returnByVal` to the already-existing `o3`.

So the copy constructor call is happening in `passByref_returnByVal`, not in your `operator=`.

Comment: oh yeah.. the temporary is getting copy constructed with modified o3 as the initializer..